# SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM on MSDN?

Tags: sql-server, msdn, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2 has supposedly been Released to Manufacturing.  Does anyone know when it's supposed to show up on MSDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just asked the MSDN Concierge, and they said it would be available in May, but said that they didn't have a fixed date yet. I'm not sure why the delay, but she didn't clarify when I pressed her.

Sorry I don't have a date - maybe somebody closer to the site can help out.

**UPDATE:** I kept pressing, and she said she'd expect it May 3rd, but that wasn't official, so we'll see what happens. I'm anxious to try it out the RTM, so I'm checking every day as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know about the other editions but express is out already. I’m running it right now, one handy thing is they have upped the size limit from 4GB to 10GB which is handy